# Open two different Popover in the same View Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, popover, mobile-application

I’m working on a mobile application using angular and ionic. I have reached the point where I need to be able to display two different popovers allowing the user to compare two images within two different popovers.

From the images below you can see an example of a popover where with the button "Pin" it must be possible to fix the popover and allow the user to open another.

[image: first popover example]

[image: second popover example]
With the current code I am allowed to only open one popover at a time (in fact when you click on the backdrop of the popover, the popover is closed)

```
  async presentPopoverBali(event) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverBaliComponent,
      event: event,
      translucent: true
      //backdropDismiss: false
    });
    return await popover.present();
  }
```

My final goal is to be able to open a popover, to click "Pin" to fix it, and then to open another popover. In such a way that it can display both popovers, with their respective images.

thank you so much in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to create multiple popover references like below.

```
const popover1 = await this.popoverController.create({
  component: PopoverBaliComponent,
  event: event,
  translucent: true
});
return await popover.present();


const popover2 = await this.popoverController.create({
  component: PopoverBaliComponent,
  event: event,
  translucent: true
});
return await popover.present();
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [alert](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert)

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'alert-example',
      templateUrl: 'alert-example.html',
      styleUrls: ['./alert-example.css'],
    })
    export class AlertExample {

      constructor(public alertController: AlertController) {}


      async presentAlertConfirmone() {
        const alert = await this.alertController.create({
          header: 'Confirm!',
          message: 'Message <strong>text</strong>!!!',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              role: 'cancel',
              cssClass: 'secondary',
              handler: (blah) => {
                console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
              }
            }, {
              text: 'Okay',
              handler: () => {

                console.log('Confirm Okay');
              }
            }
          ]
        });

        await alert.present();
      }


 async presentAlertConfirmtwo() {
        const alert = await this.alertController.create({
          header: 'Confirm!',
          message: 'Message <strong>text</strong>!!!',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              role: 'cancel',
              cssClass: 'secondary',
              handler: (blah) => {
                console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
              }
            }, {
              text: 'Okay',
              handler: () => {
                presentAlertConfirmtwo()
                console.log('Confirm Okay');
              }
            }
          ]
        });

        await alert.present();
      }
```